# Apache Camel Architecture

Tags: http, apache-camel, ibm-mq

I am working on prototyping a new web service for my company and we are considering Apache Camel as our integration framework.  Here is a quick run-down of the high-level architecture:

-IBM Websphere MQ as the queuing solution

1) we receive http request

2) asynchronously persist this request

3a) do some processing on the request

3b) send to another tier for further processing

4) asynchronously update the request record in DB

5) respond to caller

What I want to do is:

When a http request comes in, put it on a queue to be processed and wait n seconds.  If the web handler doesn't get a response in n seconds, reply to the caller with a custom message
Once the request is on the processing queue, a camel route is listening to this queue to process.  When it pulls a message from queue, put a copy of the request on a different queue to be persisted asynchronously.  Do some processing on the request.  Then send it to another queue to be further processed and wait for a response. Then put it back on the persist queue to be asynchronously updated.
Then respond to web listener.  Then web listener responds to web caller.

I am reading everything I can about Apache Camel and there is a lot of information about there.  I might be on a little bit of information overload, and any help on the following concerns would be greatly appreciated:

1)
If the web listeners use an InOut exchange (with the first processing tier) without a replyTo queue defined, it will create a temporary queue for the response.  What happens if this request times out?  I understand I can set a requestTimeout on the exchange and, if it times out, catch that exception and set a custom message.  But, will that temporary queue be killed?  Or will they build up over time as requests time out?

2) 
When it comes to scaling the processing tiers (adding more instances of those same routes on different machines), is it customary that if the instance that picks up the response (using a fixed reply to queue) is different than the instance that picked up the request, all the information about the original request is inside the message, so there is no need to share data across instances (unless of course there is data that is shared, like aggregrates and such)?

Any other tips and tricks when building a system like this would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you working in a request/reply scenario or will the response to the caller be sent to another URI?

Comment: for the initiating http request, that is req/reply... on the backend though, there will some async requests without a reply and some request/reply using temporary/fixed reply queues

Answer (score 1):

I would say this solution is too complicated and there are too many areas which are hard both in terms of maintenance and also complexity. There is too much many steps mixing async and sync communication.

Why not simply the solution to the following steps:

1. Synchronously http request
2. Put message on MQ with reply to header
3. Message is picked up and sent to backend
4. If reply is not received within a given time transaction is terminated.
5. The reply to queue is removed
6. Requestor is notified.